# Ruby on Rails Routing Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache-flex

I was developing the Application in Flex and ruby on rails.

It is working fine some times. but some times i am getting routing error.

Error: "No route matches "/index.html" with {:method=>:get}"

Here index.html is my login page

Please help me on this.

Thanks,
Ravi

Comment: Can you edit your question to show us what's in your `config/routes.rb` file please.

Comment: ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|
  map.resources :snmpv3configs
  map.resources :snmpservers
  map.resources :iolatencyhistograms
  map.resources :tasksuppressions
  map.resources :alertoccurrences
  map.resources :alertconfigs
  map.resources :systemsettings
  map.resources :targetnames
  map.resources :authentications
  map.resources :servers
  map.resources :iopathgroups
  map.resources :systemtypes
  map.resources :sensordetails
  map.resources :iolatencyconfigs
  map.resources :users
map.resource :session
  map.resources :ioscopeevents

Comment: map.resources :iolatencyresponses
map.resources :iopaths 
map.resources :users
map.resource :session
map.signup '/signup', :controller => 'users',
:action => 'new'
map.login '/login', :controller => 'sessions',
 :action => 'new'
 map.logout '/logout', :controller => 'sessions',
 :action => 'destroy'
 map.delete '/delete', :controller => 'users',
 :action => 'destroy'
 map.edit   '/edit', :controller => 'users',
 :action => 'update'
  map.delete '/deletegroup', :controller => 'iopathgroups',
 :action => 'destroy'
 map.editTarget   '/editTarget', :controller => 'Targetnames',

Comment: :action => 'update'
 map.delete '/deleteTarget', :controller => 'Targetnames',
 :action => 'destroy'
     map.editAlertConfig   '/editAlertConfig', :controller => 'Alertconfigs',
 :action => 'update'
 map.deleteAlertConfig '/deleteAlertConfig', :controller => 'Alertconfigs',
 :action => 'destroy' 
  
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
end

Comment: Please check it once ..it is very urgent for me..Even i do not have a basic knowledge on Ruby on Rails.

Thanks Jhon

Comment: add it to your question, not in the comments!

Comment: Edit your question and you can post whatever you want. The comments have no formatting as you can see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a static file public/index.html then this should be served up any time a direct request is made for it. The routing engine is simply complaining because no route for that specific path is defined.

Things to check:

- Do you have a file called public/index.html that can be served up directly?
- Do you have a route '/index.:format' defined?
- See how your routing is interpreted by running: rake routes

An easy way to add a route for this particular action is, simply:

```
route.connect '/index.:format', :controller => 'login', :action => 'new'
```

I generally add a catch-all route at the bottom of the routing table to handle mystery URLs:

```
route.connect '/*path', :controller => 'default', :action => 'not_routed'
```