# Ruby on Rails Routing Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I click a link to /index.html, I get this error:

```
No route matches "/index.html" with {:method=>:get}
```

What do I need to add in routes.rb?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby on Rails Routing Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245616/ruby-on-rails-routing-error)

Comment: not exactly. I do not have a public/index.html page, I'm using app/views/home/index.html.erb as my home page, which is the page i want /index.html to redirect to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed:

```
map.connect '/index.html', :controller => 'home'
```

Answer (score 0):

In Rails you normally want pages routing to resources. For example if you have a Project model, then you would route to /projects, which will call your ProjectsController#index action

```
#in config/routes.rb
resources :projects
```

For something like /index.html, I'll assume your looking to map to some home landing page. In this case you would want the url to be "/" and you can map that to a controller like

```
#in config/routes.rb
# This assumes you have a HomepageController with an index action and a view in app/views/homepage/index.html.erb
root :to => "homepage#index"
```

Or if you really do want "/index.html" then you can use this

```
# in config/routes.rb
get "/index" => "homepage#index"
```

Lots more can be found [in the rails docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) or in the railscasts [here](http://railscasts.com/?tag_id=14)